# how to randomly display three colors when the button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uilabel, uicolor

I've been trying to display three random colors using the labels in the screen when the button is clicked.

```
-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"Spin started.");


    NSLog(@"Message");
    NSLog(@"Message %@", nsString);


    printf("%s\n", [@"Button Press" UTF8String]);
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n", [@"Color: " UTF8String], wheelLeftColor, wheelMiddleColor, wheelRightColor);

    wheelLeftColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.9 green: 0.9 blue: 0.6 alpha: 1.0];
    wheelMiddleColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.9 green: 0.3 blue: 0.6 alpha: 1.0];
    wheelRightColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.5 green: 0.6 blue: 0.3 alpha: 1.0];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", int_num]


time_t seed = time(0);
srandom((int)seed);

int num = random() % 3;
```

I am not sure how to make this work. I have an idea but not sure how to implement it, 
in the action method, pass the label object and the color code
The problem here is how to use ints to store a value 1 - 3 to denote the color for each wheel?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested yet but it should work.

```
- (UIColor *)randomColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:[self randomColorComponentValue] green:[self randomColorComponentValue] blue:[self randomColorComponentValue] alpha:1];
}

- (CGFloat)randomColorComponentValue
{
     CGFloat random = (CGFloat)arc4random()%255;
     return random/255.0f;
}

- (IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender
{
    wheelLeftColor.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
    wheelMiddleColor.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
    wheelRightColor.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
}
```

Comment: Here i am having an issue with CGFloat,

Comment: **This works well, but my concern is that i want to randomly display colors from the predefined color values. So, after a 3 sec time, it should randomly display the colors. For example, for the leftwheel, it should have to display any one of the three colors. for the middle wheel, it should display any of the three, and likewise for the right. it's more like a slot machine spin. your time is appreciated** @Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Answer by oscar is also the same and better detailed. But for a concise method here goes.

```
-(UIColor *)randomCOlor{

   return [UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4Random()%10)/10.0f green:(arc4Random()%10)/10.0f blue:(arc4Random()%10)/10.0f alpha:1];

}
```

so

```
UIColor *someColor = [self randomColor];
```

**Update:**
IF you want to select a random color from pre-defined values, you can use the belo code:

Let `color1,color2,color3` be three(any number according to your requirement) UIColor object. Then you can select a random value like below and set color of the label after the delay of 3s:

```
NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1,color2,color3,nil];
NSInteger index = arc4random()%[colorArray count];
UIColor *selColor = [colorArray objecatAtIndex:index-1];
```

and then pass this color object and label object as you mentioned in the question to set the color.

you can use `performSelector:withObject:withDelay:` to call a method after a delay.

Comment: **Thanks for you time but,my concern is that i want to randomly display colors from the predefined color values. So, after a 3 sec time, it should randomly display the colors. For example, for the leftwheel, it should have to display any one of the three colors. for the middle wheel, it should display any of the three, and likewise for the right. it's more like a slot machine spin. your time is appreciated** @Rakesh

Comment: If you want to select a random color from a set of random value , i have update the code.